# How to create a hotkey to open diigo in Chrome browser?

Tags: hotkeys

I'm using diigo extension in Chrome browser and feel quite tired of clicking the diigo icon every time I want to bookmark. I'm looking for a way to have a hotkey for it but can't find it in the option of diigo.

I tried [solution suggested by makeuseof website](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/open-google-chrome-bookmarks-keyboard-shortcuts/) but the [diigo booklet](http://www.diigo.com/tools/diigolet) doesn't work as great as the extension - it requires to sign in again and again... !?

If you have any work-around to get the hotkey for diigo, please share! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I patched the Diigo Chrome Extension v1.6.3.0 to support bookmarking via Ctrl-D

http://martin.bz/post/Diigo-Chrome-Extension-Hotkey.aspx

Comment: Would be lovely to have the hotkey as Ctrl-D-G instead of Ctrl-D. You are overwritting a default hotkey which is not favored, be me at least :)

Comment: With the key `Ctrl-D-D`, I'll choose your answer as accepted

Comment: I don't really know how to implement a double key sequence.
But if you want to change the hotkey, just edit the file, look at the end and change bookmarkKeyChar.